# Why I am getting view mail not found?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send email in Laravel via my post route which has the following code:

```
 Mail::send('mail',['name','Ripon Uddin Arman'],function($message){
        $message->to('rislam252@gmail.com')->subject("Email Testing with Laravel");
        $message->from('clhg52@gmail.com','Creative Losser Hopeless Genius');
    });
```

When I run the code I get the error:

> View [mail] not found.

I am using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

Comment: you don't have a view named 'mail' ... why would there be one?

Comment: Did you ran php artisan view:clear ?

Comment: Why do I need a view I just want to send email

Comment: The view creates the body of the message

Comment: Can I do it wihtout view

Comment: @user123456 You can, but it's honestly harder and a bit silly. Laravel has a built-in mail templating system to quickly build basic HTML emails. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#markdown-mailables

Comment: You can use your existing code with a blank `mail.blade.php` file in your `views` directory, and it'll work as written. If you don't need a body, then `Mail::raw('', ...)` as written below is also fine. Lots of options when using Laravel 

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to send a raw email you can use the `raw` method:

```
Mail::raw($content, function ($message) { ... });
```

If you want to send an HTML email you can use the `html` method:

```
Mail::html($htmlContent, function ($message) { ... });
```

These do not require any view as you are passing the entire message body/part to the method.